# How to send email in Magento 2 programmatically without creating custom module?

Tags: magento2, php, email, custom, script

I need to create a custom script which allows me to send a simple test email with email addresses of Sender, Receiver CC Bcc; Subject line and Body of Email. How could I do this in Magento 2.x?

----- Update -----

I tried to send email by creating a function in my custom script but it didn't work:

Here is my function which I created in my custom script.

```
function sendEmail(){
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $transport = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder'); 
    $templateVars = [
                        'message'    => "This is a test email."
                    ];
    $templateId =1;
    $storeId =1;

    $data = $transport
                    ->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
                    ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $storeId])
                    ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                    ->setFrom([
                                'name' => 'Test',
                                'email' => 'test@gmail.com'
                                ])
                    ->addTo(['test@gmail.com','test@gmail.com'])
                    ->setReplyTo('test@gmail.com')
                    ->addBcc('test@gmail.com')
                    ->getTransport();
    $data->sendMessage();
}
```

**ERROR:**

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Email template '1' is not defined. in /var/www/html/magento232sd/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Config.php:225 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento232sd/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Config.php(166): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Config->_getInfo(1, 'type') #1 /var/www/html/magento232sd/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template.php(215): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Config->getTemplateType(1) #2 /var/www/html/magento232sd/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php(709): Magento\Email\Model\Template->getType() #3 /var/www/html/magento232sd/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php(331): Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate->isPlain() #4 /var/www/html/magento232sd/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template.php(379): Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate->getProcessedTemplate(Array) #5 /var/www/html/magento232sd/vendor/magent in **/var/www/html/magento232sd/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Config.php** on line **225**

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37545063 It send email using php

Comment: Hii @user55548 it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There are some locations in magento you can view as your example for send email

Module SendFriend
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/SendFriend/Model/SendFriend.php#L171

Module Contact
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Contact/Model/Mail.php#L63

Module Customer
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/AccountManagement.php#L1302
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/EmailNotification.php#L248

Module Newsletter
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php

Module Sitemap
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Sitemap/Model/EmailNotification.php#L69